Sqlalchemy + FastAPI. Return ORM model result with nested childs
I have table "categories" with subcategories. Subcategories are determined by "parent_id".

I want to find a way to return an object from FastAPI's endpoint like this:
[
  {
    "name": "Category",
    "id": "599a5906-1ba1-45ca-9af9-bac2e1513519",
    "created_at": "2024-07-17T21:25:24.590781",
    "child": [
      {
        "name": "SubCategory",
        "id": "bc540161-e390-4982-87a8-f8eff47204b6",
        "created_at": "2024-07-17T21:25:43.307017",
        "child": null
      }
    ]
  }
]

SQlAlchemy model (here I created a relationship as adviced in this question):
from sqlalchemy import ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.orm import Mapped, mapped_column, relationship

from database._types import created_at, uuid, uuidpk
from database.engine import Base


class CategoriesModel(Base):
    __tablename__ = "categories"

    id: Mapped[uuidpk]
    parent_id: Mapped[uuid | None] = mapped_column(ForeignKey("categories.id"))
    name: Mapped[str]
    created_at: Mapped[created_at]

    child: Mapped[list["CategoriesModel"]] = relationship(
        "CategoriesModel",
        remote_side=[parent_id],
        uselist=True
    )

Query method from repository:
class SQLAlchemyRepository[T]:
    def __init__(self, session: AsyncSession) -> None:
        self._model: MappedClassProtocol = get_args(self.__orig_bases__[0])[0]
        self._session = session


class CategoriesRepository(SQLAlchemyRepository[CategoriesModel]):
    async def get_many(self) -> list[Row]:
        stmt = (
            select(self._model.id, self._model.name, self._model.created_at)
            .order_by(self._model.name)
        )
        res = await self._session.execute(stmt)
        return res.all()

Pydantic models:
from datetime import datetime
from _types import uuid


class SQLAlchemyMappedModel(BaseModel):
    class Config:
        from_attributes = True


class CategorySchema(SQLAlchemyMappedModel):
    name: str


class CategoryOut(CategorySchema):
    id: uuid
    created_at: datetime
    child: list["CategorySchema"] = []

Endpoint:
@router.get("/", summary="Categories")
async def get_categories(
    uow: Annotated[IUnitOfWork, Depends(get_uow)],
) -> list[CategoryOut]:
    async with uow:
        res = await uow.categories.get_many()
        await uow.commit()
    return res

SQLAlchemy doesn't return "child". So the result is different from expected.
[
  {
    "name": "Category",
    "id": "599a5906-1ba1-45ca-9af9-bac2e1513519",
    "created_at": "2024-07-17T21:25:24.590781",
    "child": []
  },
  {
    "name": "SubCategory",
    "id": "bc540161-e390-4982-87a8-f8eff47204b6",
    "created_at": "2024-07-17T21:25:43.307017",
    "child": []
  }
]

I've decided not to include code unrelated to the question (FastAPI dependencies, UOW), but if a minimally reproducible example is needed, I can do that.

The problem was in the incorrect query. It should be like this:
from sqlalchemy.orm import joinedload


class CategoriesRepository(SQLAlchemyRepository[CategoriesModel]):
    async def get_many(self) -> list[Row]:
        stmt = (
            select(self._model)
            .options(joinedload(self._model.child))
            .order_by(self._model.name)
        )
        res = await self._session.execute(stmt)
        return res.unique().scalars().all()

In this way ORM generate a correct SQL query (print(stmt)):
SELECT categories.id, categories.parent_id, categories.name, categories.created_at, categories_1.id AS id_1, categories_1.parent_id AS parent_id_1, categories_1.name AS name_1, categories_1.created_at AS created_at_1
    FROM categories
    LEFT OUTER JOIN categories AS categories_1
        ON categories.id = categories_1.parent_id
ORDER BY categories.name

Some examples about sync usage cases could be found in the official docs. But I couldn't find any about asynchronous use.
Also I made a mistake in pydantic model:
class CategoryOut(CategorySchema):
    id: uuid
    created_at: datetime
    child: list["CategorySchema"] = []

child field should be annotated by its class:
child: list["CategoryOut"] = []

I'm not still sure if it's the best solution. I will be glad to read the answers from experienced people.

Yes, it's correct way to do what you want. The only thing - I would limit the recursion by using list["CategorySchemaWithoutChildren"] = [] as a type for child. CategorySchemaWithoutChildren is the same as CategorySchema, but without child field

Yes, it should work fine with the depth no more than 1. I found the param join_depth from relationship in SQLAlchemy that limits it on database layer.
